# Создание экземпляра класса range

Tags: python, python-3.x

В Python имеется класс range, который генерирует последовательность из чисел. При его вызове можно указать один, два или три параметра. Но я не могу понять, как именно это работает? Почему я могу указать (stop) или (start, stop) в параметрах?

Если бы start был необязательным параметром (start = 0), то stop не мог бы находится позади него, так как обязательные параметры указывается первыми. Так же в Python'е нет перегрузки конструкторов. Из кода единственное, что я смог узнать: ничего:

```py
    def __init__(self, stop): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        pass
```

Так вот, мне интересно, можно ли сделать что-то подобное или это реализуется только на уровне исходного кода Python?

Comment: `range()` - встроенная функция, которая всегда доступна. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range . Что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: range - не функция, а класс и по ссылке это указано. Я хотел бы узнать, как реализована передача разного количества параметров в конструктор? Это особенность этого класса или для своего можно такое повторить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это делается примерно так

```
def __init__(self, start, end=None, step=1):
    if end is None:
        self.start = 0
        self.end = start
    else:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
    self.step = step
```

Comment: +1, но рекомендую `if end is None:` т.к. `None` - синглетон.

Comment: @MarianD, поправил, спасибо.